# How to create SQL Query that concatenates and parses value in result set

Tags: mysql, sql, singlestore

How to make an SQL query for a table based on the following conditions:

- Result is a single column that concatenates all fields delimited by a dash into a single string (ex: *FieldA-FieldB-FieldC-FieldD-FieldE*)
- If a given field is NULL or if the field's value is a string such as "**EMPTY**" or "**NA**", do not concatenate that field's value into the result string

Example **Table Person (FirstName, LastName, Street, City, State)**:

```
Bob | Dylan | 555 Street | Mountain View | California
Ally | M | NULL | Seattle | Washington
Jan | Van | EMPTY | EMPTY | Oregon
Nancy | Finn | EMPTY | EMPTY | NA
Don | William | NULL | EMPTY | Illinois
```

Result:

```
Bob-Dylan-555 Street-Mountain View-California
Ally-M-Seattle-Washington
Jan-Van-Oregon
Nancy-Finn
Don-William-Illinois
```

I know this can be done programatically, but wanted to know if this can be done in SQL and if it would be more efficient to do so in the query itself.

Comment: First of all, tag correct RDBMS, second: hint would be `Case` expression or `ISNULL` function with concatenation operator `'+'` in case of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks.  sorry I updated the tag to indicate that this is for MySQL / MemSQL RDMS. Question:
1) How about handling the fields which have specific text such as "EMPTY" AND/OR "NA".
2) Would SQL's CONCAT() function be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully-baked solution for SQL Server 2017 and above:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person p
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT STRING_AGG(NULLIF(NULLIF(val, 'EMPTY'), 'NA'), '-') 
   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY n) AS val
   FROM (VALUES (1, p.FirstName), (2, p.LastName),(3, p.Street),
                (4,p.City), (5, p.State)) z(n, val)
 )sub;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4d717ec46e7548e7b16ee78b6bdf9c3f)**

---

MySQL version using [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

> CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the arguments. If the separator is NULL, the result is NULL.
>
> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, **it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument.**

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',
  NULLIF(NULLIF(FirstName, 'EMPTY'), 'NA'),
  NULLIF(NULLIF(LastName, 'EMPTY'), 'NA'),
  NULLIF(NULLIF(Street, 'EMPTY'), 'NA'),
  NULLIF(NULLIF(City, 'EMPTY'), 'NA'),
  NULLIF(NULLIF(State, 'EMPTY'), 'NA')) AS r
FROM Person p;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6b89dbe650cb49ce15c12a5788878a42)**

Comment: Thank you. What if the field is NULL? For ex: if Street is NULL, I'd like for it to produce    FirstName-LastName-City-State

Answer (score 0):

Your select should be something like this:

```
select isnull(FieldA,'')+ '-' + isnull (FieldB,'') + '-' + isnull (FieldC,'') ....
```

and so on ..

This will work on MS SQL server if you don't want '-' if previous field is null than you should use case statement.

If you want to replace also 'Empty' or 'NULL' strings than you should use:

```
select replace(replace( isnull(FieldA+'-','') , 'Empty' , ''),'Null', '')
```

I have modified isnull() by Nitin_g3 observation.

Comment: Thanks. Question:
1) How about handling the fields which have specific text such as "EMPTY" AND/OR "NA".
2) Would SQL's CONCAT() function be useful?

Also... sorry I updated the tag to indicate that this is for MySQL / MemSQL RDMS.

Comment: I would rather go with:
`select isnull(FieldA+'-','') + isnull (FieldB+'-','') + isnull (FieldC+'-','') ....`
So that in case there is a null It would not put more than one '-' in between columns values.

Comment: @codeshark: Than you should use also Replace over isnull()
replace( isnull(FieldA+'-','') , 'Empty' , '' )

Answer (score 0):

first, use **CONCAT** to concatenate the fields.
then use **REPLACE** to replace NULL values

```
SELECT REPLACE( CONCAT( field1,  "-", field2 ,  "-", field3) ,  "NULL",  "EMPTY" ) 
FROM  `table`
```

Comment: Thanks; what if the field value is NULL but not the string "NULL"?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    SELECT ISNULL(FirstName,'') + '-' + 
           ISNULL (LastName,'') + '-' + 
           ISNULL (City,'') + '-' + 
           ISNULL (State,'') 
   FROM  Person
```

OR LIKE THIS

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(FirstName,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE FirstName + '-' +  
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(LastName,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE LastName + '-' + 
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(City,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE City + '-' + 
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(State,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE State + '-' END AS 
ColumnName
   FROM  Person
```